# Breakout container in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="jumbotron"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make the jumbotron full page width although it is inside the container?

Comment: You can't easily (AFAIK, not at all without JavaScript). Why not take it out of the container?

Comment: I would have to change the whole wordpress theme which will brake it

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention that in the question @daniel

Comment: @daniel I understand. Would you be open to a JavaScript solution?

Comment: I think this should be done with css only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `container-fluid` instead

```css
.jumbotron {
  border: 1px red solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you have `.container-fluid`  already inside a `.container` which will be restrained to its fixed `width`

Comment: so I have to change the whole wordpress theme?

Comment: Its depends on what you want to do